# Repatable race() operator in rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to implement an input component that would execute search either when input value changes (debounced by 500ms), or enter key is pressed. I'd like to avoid search term being emitted twice - both on debounced input, and on enter pressed.

Unfortunately this is still the case in this scenario:

1. Type something into input
2. Press enter after ~100ms - search is executed
3. Deebounce time passes and another search is executed.

What am I missing?

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u5orqc?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { race, repeat, Subject, Subscription, take, debounceTime } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search" (input)="inputChanged($any($event.target).value)" (keydown.enter)="enterPressed($any($event.target).value)"/>

    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let message of messages">{{message}}</li>
    </ul>
  `,
})
export class App {
  messages: string[] = [];
  inputChanged$: Subject<string> = new Subject();
  inputChangedDebounced$: Subject<string> = new Subject();
  enterPressed$: Subject<string> = new Subject();

  inputChangedDebouncedSubscription: Subscription = this.inputChanged$
    .pipe(debounceTime(500))
    .subscribe((value) =>
      this.inputChangedDebounced$.next(`Debounced input with value: ${value}`)
    );

  executeSearchSubscription: Subscription = race(
    this.inputChangedDebounced$,
    this.enterPressed$
  )
    .pipe(take(1), repeat())
    .subscribe((value) => {
      this.messages.push(value);
    });

  inputChanged(targetValue?: any) {
    const value: string = targetValue;
    this.inputChanged$.next(value);
  }

  enterPressed(targetValue?: any) {
    const value: string = targetValue;
    this.enterPressed$.next(`Enter pressed with value: ${value}`);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

Answer (score 1):

I could see an alternative solution where you could use RxJS `fromEvent` function with Angular template ref variable to listen to the `keydown` events. As for `input` events, you could for eg. use a reactive form, and use it's `valueChanges` observable to listen to it.

The both observables could then be merged using the RxJS `merge` function to which you could apply the `debouceTime` opeartor.

Try the following

```js
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { debounceTime, fromEvent, merge } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="inputForm">
      <input #inputElem type="search" formControlName="search" placeholder="Search"/>
    </form>

    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let message of messages">{{message}}</li>
    </ul>
  `,
})
export class App implements AfterViewInit {
  public messages: string[] = [];
  public inputForm!: FormGroup;

  @ViewChild('inputElem')
  private inputElem!: ElementRef;

  constructor(private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.inputForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      search: [''],
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const input$ = this.inputForm.controls['search'].valueChanges;
    const keyEnter$ = fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(
      this.inputElem.nativeElement,
      'keydown'
    ).pipe(filter((e: KeyboardEvent) => e.key === 'Enter'));

    merge(input$, keyEnter$)
      .pipe(
        map(() => this.inputForm.value.search),
        debounceTime(500)
      )
      .subscribe((searchInput) =>
        this.messages.push(`Emission: ${searchInput}`)
      );
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

I've updated your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bfdnl8?file=src%2Fmain.ts)